# How i can get element by selector of chrome?

Tags: javascript

I copied a selector from Chrome and I need get the same element in JavaScript.

My selector is `#pruebaxx > div > div > ol:nth-child(2) > li > input`.

I tried the following snippet, but it did not work as expected:

```
document.getElementById('#pruebaxx > div > div > ol:nth-child(2) > li > input').innerHTML
```

Comment: Try document.querySelector. But your selector is awful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) takes an element id as argument. **Use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead**:

```
document.querySelector('#pruebaxx > div > div > ol:nth-child(2) > li > input').innerHTML
```